# Writing Excel Extract program in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write an extract program that will find the values and add them together. I just want to find the first number and then find the last number in that column. The problem is there are empty spaces and can't use the cell number because they could change.

| # | 1st column | 2nd column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |  |
| 2 | 10 |  |
| 3 | 8 |  |
| 4 |  | 20 |
| 5 |  | 52 |

```
    string fileExcel = @"C:\test.xlsx";
            var xlApplication = new Excel.Application();
            var xlWorkbook = xlApplication.Workbooks.Open(fileExcel);
            var xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

            var xlRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Columns["B:B"];
            var foundRange = xlRange.Find("1st column", Type.Missing, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, 
                Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            xlRange = foundRange.FindNext(xlRange);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the range of columns/rows of interest and test for when an empty cell is encountered, using something like this

```
  public bool IsEmpty(Excel.Worksheet sheet, int row, int col)
  {
    return sheet.Cells[row, col].Text == string.Empty;
  }
```

Here's how to find the first non-blank cell in a sheet

```
  // a blank sheet inn a blank workbook...
  var xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
  var wbk = xl.Workbooks.Add();
  var sht = wbk.Sheets[1];
  // insert a value somewhere
  sht.Cells[4, 5].Value = 999;
  var r = sht.UsedRange.Cells[1, 1].Row();
  var c = sht.UsedRange.Cells[1, 1].Column();
  Console.WriteLine($"Cells[{r},{c}].Value = {sht.Cells[r,c].Value}");
```

result

```
Cells[4,5].Value = 999
```

Comment: Is there a way to find 1st column then grab every value after the cell in that column?

Comment: @m.woods I've updated my answer but in future you should post individual well-formed questions, crediting the (best) answer.  Then if you have another, post a new question. G'luck